# batch file does not executing psql query after connected server

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file, psql

I want to connect to my psql and copy them as csv.
My databases are numbers.
Thats in my text file (every line is one number)
`011`
`012`
`013`
`014`

and I use a loop to read numbers and put them to connect and copy from database

```
        FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (600.txt) DO (
            psql -h 600-%%x my_server
            \copy "(select '600' as column1, column2, column3, column4) TO '600-%%x.csv' CSV;"

        )
```

the file will be read correctly, connect to the server also works but after it connected nothing will happens, and the copy query will not be execute, can someone please tell me why my copy query does not call after connecting to database.

Comment: The command you are trying to run inside the PSQL shell is actually running in the Command shell where the batch file executes in. Tahe a look at the PQSL documentation to find out whether it supports a script file argument…

Comment: `\copy "(select '600' as column1, column2, column3, column4) TO '600-%%x.csv' CSV;"` is not a recognisable command to `cmd.exe`. I assume that it is supposed to be a command for `psql`, so you cannot have it separate. Have you thought of using the `-c` option?

Comment: I add them both in 1 line and seperate them with `-c` but it didn't work and told me that it can't do the copy because it didn't connect but when they are seperate it connect and does not do the copy